# how to make iframe 100% with no scroll bar

Tags: html, iframe, scroll

I am trying to represent mobile version of the website. I used iframe with no scrolling and created div with custom scroll bar. It almost works, except that every background image is zoomed in. Just look at the fiddle example, you will see what I mean. I think it is because I set height to be fixed 6000, but I could not figure out how to make height of iframe to be 100% with no scrolling bar of the iframe. Can someone help to make iframe 100% with no scroll bar, but with fixed width and custom div scroll bar as on this fiddle example. 
http://jsfiddle.net/KMzgm/3387/

```
 .scroll {
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;

   overflow: scroll;
}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}


.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

    <div class="scroll">

 <iframe src="http://spruce.yourwebsite.directincorporation.com/home/" height="6000" width="400"
scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting overflow-y to hidden.

```
iframe {
  width:500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That breaks the whole div scrolling and set the width to be the div's width.

Answer (score 0):

here you go.
read about  [vh and vw units.](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)!

http://jsfiddle.net/KMzgm/3389/

```
    .scroll {
   width: 500px;
   height: 100vh;}
```

Comment: But that does not work with scrollbar NO, it only works with scrollbar of iframe, which I try to avoid.